# Use Custom Domain for Openshift 3.9 Routes

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I am completely new to Networking and setting up Domains. But recently I bought a domain `(xyz-demos.com)` and I want to use it as a domain to my Openshift App Routes. I did not find any proper guide on how to do it.

In Openshift I have 3 apps running with routes as,

```
appname-namespace.serverIP.nip.io
app1-namespace1.35.55.55.555.nip.io
app2-namespace2.35.55.55.555.nip.io
app3-namespace3.35.55.55.555.nip.io
```

any other app deployed in the future will just append its name,
`appName-namespace.serverIP.nip.io`

How do I map my custom domain so that all my Openshift apps use it? Something like, how to replace 
`35.55.55.555.nip.io` with `xyz-demos.com`

```
appname-namespace.xyz-demos.com
app1-namespace1.xyz-demos.com
app2-namespace2.xyz-demos.com
app3-namespace3.xyz-demos.com
```

I am using a domain from GoDaddy and Openshift Origin 3.9.

Note - The reason why I am going with custom domains, is that
`*.nip.io` domains are restricted in my office network as Dynamic DNS and I do not know a way around it.

Comment: Pro tips for questions here: (1) please do not offer voting advice. If a question is a duplicate, marking it as "not a duplicate" will not affect that status; (2) requests for tutorials and blog articles makes a question off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of configuration what you need to do in the cluster creation time, I mean, in the inventory file of your cluster creation you need to configure the following fields:

**openshift_master_cluster_hostname=**ocp.xyz-demos.com
**openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname=**ocp.xyz-demos.com
**openshift_master_default_subdomain=**xyz-demos.com

Dont forget to configure the certs of your domain:

**openshift_master_overwrite_named_certificates=**True
**openshift_master_named_certificates=**[{"certfile": "/etc/ansible/certs/xyz-demos.com.crt", "keyfile": "/etc/ansible/certs/xyz-demos.com.key", "cafile": "/etc/ansible/certs/ca-xyz-demos.com.crt"}]

And force the Routers to add this new subdomain in the new Routes:

**openshift_hosted_router_force_subdomain=**xyz-demos.com

Thoses fields are responsible to expose your admin console and application routes.